# Please stop designing SE on Mac 720 inch displays

Tags: discussion, support, bug, design, suggestion

Most of the time, when I code, I work on a non-HD, non-retina, non-glitter, non-shiny, non-Mac Laptop. And honestly, how would I read the content when there's no space left for content?

> [image]

Comment: I miss what precisely is your issue? Content below the fold?

Comment: @Rarst That I got ~200px left for the content as the sticky top bar/info box takes ~45-50% of the height of my viewport.

Comment: Stop using your Playstation for serious work.

Comment: I wish I had a 720 inch display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Click on the less link to collapse the instructions.

[image]

Comment: your title was more verbose than this _tiny_ link... +1